# Unable to completely remove QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am using PyQt6. My `QMainWindow` class uses to middle click of the mouse to perform an action. The app can launch a little `QWidget` that also uses the middle click to perform an action. When this widget is open it disables the middle click from the main window. When closing the widget, the main window enables its ability to use the middle click again but I noticed that it raises errors as it is still trying to call the function connected to middle click inside the widget.

I am trying to *completely* delete the QWidget so that this doesn't happen anymore.

I have tried:
`del(widget)`
`widget.destroy()`
`widget.deleteLater()`
`widget.close()`
`widget = None`

None of these work as it still raises `RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type <widget> has been deleted`

If it doesn't delete it properly, it simply calls both middle click connections.

How do I completely remove the widget so that nothing can refer to the widget anymore?

Example:

```py
# app.py

import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

from main_window import MainWindow


class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, argv: list) -> None:
        super().__init__(argv)

        self.main_window = MainWindow()

        self.main_window.show()


app = App(sys.argv)

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

```py
# main_window.py

import mouse
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
)

from test_widget import TestWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton("Open Widget", self)

        self.test_widget = None

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_widget)

        mouse.on_middle_click(self.test_function)

    def open_widget(self) -> None:
        self.test_widget = TestWidget(self)

        self.test_widget.show()

    def close_widget(self, widget: QWidget) -> None:
        widget.deleteLater()

        self.test_widget = None

    def test_function(self) -> None:
        if self.test_widget is not None:
            return

        print("Main Window")
```

```py
# test_widget

import mouse
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QLineEdit,
    QWidget,
)

class TestWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, main_window) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.main_window = main_window

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit(self)

        mouse.on_middle_click(self.test_function)

    def closeEvent(self, _) -> None:
        self.main_window.close_widget(self)

    def test_function(self) -> None:
        print(self.line_edit.text())
```

I cannot share the original code as it is sensitive, but in the example it follows the same process

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Why are you using the `mouse` module? This would create a closure to the TestWidget instance: calling `del` does *not* destroy the object, it only removes the reference. At the same time, while you're destroying the actual QWidget, the python object still exists (because it's still connected to the `mouse` function).

Comment: The `mouse` module is the best way I have found to pick up the middle click, even when the app isn't in focus. I need it to be able to detect it for as long as the app is open and when I did my rounds trying to figure this out I found that only the `mouse` module works

Answer (score 1):

I've been most successful in deleting PyQT objects by just setting their `parent` to `None`. Try

```
def close_widget(self, widget: QWidget) -> None:
        widget.deleteLater()
        self.test_widget.parent = None
        self.test_widget = None
```

Comment: ```python
File "<widget>.py", line 48, in <widget function>
    if self.line_edit.text() == "":
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted
```
It still raises the same error

Comment: I have updated the example to reproduce the error, and using this solution doesn't work

Comment: I don't see the change in your question, did you edit it? Note that the important part is the `self.test_widget.parent = None` to disconnect the widget from the parent, which will delete it on the C++ side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @musicamante for the tip in the right direction.

I solved the issue by unbinding the `mouse` module from all hooks, deleting the window, and then re-assigning the desired hooks. The reason I unbind all of them is because `mouse` raises an error if I just unbind the one so I just made a simple workaround.

Code:

```py
# app.py

import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

from main_window import MainWindow


class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, argv: list) -> None:
        super().__init__(argv)

        self.main_window = MainWindow()

        self.main_window.show()


app = App(sys.argv)

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

```py
# main_window.py

import mouse
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
)

from test_widget import TestWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton("Open Widget", self)

        self.test_widget = None

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_widget)

        mouse.on_middle_click(self.test_function)

    def open_widget(self) -> None:
        self.test_widget = TestWidget(self)

        self.test_widget.show()

    def close_widget(self, widget: QWidget) -> None:
        widget.deleteLater()

        mouse.unhook_all()
        mouse.on_middle_click(self.test_function)

        self.test_widget = None

    def test_function(self) -> None:
        if self.test_widget is not None:
            return

        print("Main Window")
```

```py
# test_widget.py

import mouse
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QLineEdit,
    QWidget,
)

class TestWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, main_window) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.main_window = main_window

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit(self)

        mouse.on_middle_click(self.test_function)

    def closeEvent(self, _) -> None:
        # mouse.unhook(self.test_function) - this doesn't work

        self.main_window.close_widget(self)

    def test_function(self) -> None:
        print(self.line_edit.text())
```

Comment: A possible and more OOP friendly solution to avoid unbinding and rebinding again could be to create a custom signal for the application and generally emit it when the button is pressed, then only connect the signal to the windows that need it: this will automatically disconnect the signal when the second window is deleted. Note that the signal approach should also be used in your close function as "child" objects should not directly access "parent" functions: create a "closed" signal and connect it in the main window when you create the other.